# Does the Android emulator update your app when you save your code?

Tags: android, emulation

What I was wondering is that if I have the emulator open, and I then edit some stuff in the code in eclipse will the emulator update itself so the changes I have made will be there? Will this work or do I just have to do something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not. You have to redeploy ("Run as Android-Application") manually.

Btw [App Inventor](http://www.appinventor.mit.edu/) does support this, so maybe some day...